# D3.csv read in promises

Tags: javascript, d3.js, promise

I am working through Scott Murray's Interactive Data Visualization for the Web.  The book is centered around d3 version 4 and I am trying to use d3 version 5.  I am new to javascript, but it had been going fairly well until I came to the main difference between version 4 and 5, which is reading in data with promises.

I have been stuck on [this example](https://github.com/alignedleft/d3-book/blob/master/chapter_07/09_time_scale.html).  I have made what I thought were the appropriate changes looking at other examples such as [this one](http://datawanderings.com/2018/08/15/d3-js-v5-promise-syntax-examples/) and the [introduction to promises from the D3 author](https://beta.observablehq.com/@mbostock/introduction-to-promises).

I have tried 2 approaches.

THe first only changes line 36 in the linked example above.

It has:

```
d3.csv("time_scale_data.csv", rowConverter, function(data) {
```

Where I have:

```
d3.csv("time_scale_data.csv", rowConverter).then(function(data){...
```

The second approach is trying to wrap everything up in an async function as I have seen so the beginning is

```
async function makePlot(){
            //Load in the data
                const dataset = await d3.csv("time_scale_data.csv", rowConverter)
```

I get the same result both ways.  It renders some svg text Dec 31 for every data point, but dec 31 is not even a single point, and I can see values in the console, but none of the values match my csv.

How do I get [this example](https://github.com/alignedleft/d3-book/blob/master/chapter_07/09_time_scale.html) to work with promises?

## UPDATE:

This is embarrassing but I will leave this up for an example if anyone else is struggling with this.

The above works.  I had one of the columns incorrectly labeled in the csv and had corrected it, but even with a hard refresh it still didn't fix it, I needed to hard refresh and remove the cache.  Multiple hours of my life :(

Comment: Make sure that the first line of the CSV contains a delimiter-separated list of column names. https://github.com/d3/d3-dsv#dsv_parse

Comment: Thanks @Jaime, the code now works.  I had not pasted the full column name over when I copied the csv, and had corrected it, but it was still in the cache.  Everything works since that has been resolved.